# OR condition in visualforce page throwing syntax error

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Contains(OR(disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.loan__Loan_Product_Name__r.Product_Type__c,'Line of Credit'), (disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.loan__Loan_Product_Name__r.Product_Type__c,'Working Capital')) && con.Id == disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.Broker__c && disbursal.Exclude_Refinance_Disbursal_Transaction__c >0}" >
```

Can somebody help me on this to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You had your Contains() / OR() wrapping wrong (I think):

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!
   AND (
        OR ( Contains( disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.loan__Loan_Product_Name__r.Product_Type__c,'Line of Credit'),
             Contains( disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.loan__Loan_Product_Name__r.Product_Type__c,'Working Capital') 
        ),
        con.Id == disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.Broker__c,
        disbursal.Exclude_Refinance_Disbursal_Transaction__c > 0 
   )
}"> Content </apex:outputPanel>
```

When you write it as I have, then you will be able to debug it easily - it's clear the order that params are being evaluated and you can see errors more easily.

I could tell this because `Contains` takes a string as a parameter and you were passing it a Boolean value: `Contains(OR(...`

It's probably best to evaluate this sort of complicated logic in the controller if you can - it's a lot easier to determine this in Apex.

Comment: Should i put this piece of code in the VF page only and try debugging?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is working for me.

Comment: There the syntax error was 'expected string but was boolean'

Comment: Ok, so that's easy to find. Look at each line of the calculation and determine the data type. Then selectively remove 1 line at a time and try saving - then you will find what is wrong.

Comment: `con.Id == disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.Broker__c,` and 
        `disbursal.Exclude_Refinance_Disbursal_Transaction__c > 0` could both have data type issues - check them and make sure they are the correct data type.